# Re-arrange unsorted array such that it follows specified pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array of names such as:

```
let names = [Jewel, Crown, Rob, Rob, Jewel, Crown]
```

How can I re-arrange the array so that it would be in the following order:

```
[Jewel, Crown, Rob, Jewel, Crown, Rob]
```

Basically this function should accept an unsorted array of names and re-arrange it such that it returns an array following the same order in the example above. I was thinking of using the .filter method in javascript but I'm having trouble figuring out how I would implement something like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, you have to loop till an already word was previously found and then sort them according to their indices?

Comment: Why not just take the sorted array? It would make sense if you had an array of objects and want to sort those according to some property and you have an array with the sort order for this property.

Comment: @maraca I'm not sure what you mean by "why not just take the sorted array" can you clarify? The point of this function is to sort an unsorted array so it results in the order shown in the example above.

Comment: Well the question is hard to understand. If you would have said that you have rules which name has to follow another it would have been much clearer. Still not clear why Jewel has to be first. Anyway it looks to me that you could just count the number of appearances of each name, put them in a new array as long as it is possible to follow the rules and then fill up with the rest. O(n)

Comment: The array in the question is just an example, essentially the function i'm trying to create should be able to accept **any array of names** and then sort it so that the result that is returned is sorted in a similar way as the example above. It doesn't matter which name comes first as long as it's sorted so that it follows the pattern in the question. Hope that provides some clarification.

Comment: That's really not sufficiently precise. What should it do with names which don't repeat, or don't repeat the right number of times? And your example seems to imply that the names are sorted in order of first appearance of each unique name, and that this order is then repeated. Are those two conditions required? Or is it only necessary that once the order is established, that it be repeated? (Those two possibilities have different consequences and different implementations.) If you're going to ask someone to do your task for you, you should at least be extremely clear about the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function. In addition it adds to the end of the list the elements that are not part of the sorting pattern.

```js
let names = ["Jewel", "Crown", "Rob", "Rob", "Jewel", "Crown"];
let namesWithUnknown = ["Jewel", "Crown", "Rob", "Rob", "Jewel", "Test unknown name", "Crown"];

function sortNames(unsortedNames) {
    const unsortedNamesCopy = [...unsortedNames]
    const res = [];
    const nextNames = {"Jewel": "Crown", "Crown": "Rob", "Rob": "Jewel"};
    let nextName = "Jewel";
    let count = 0;

    while (unsortedNamesCopy.length !== 0 && count < 3) {
        count++;
        if (unsortedNamesCopy.includes(nextName)) {
            res.push(nextName);
            unsortedNamesCopy.splice(unsortedNamesCopy.findIndex(name => name === nextName), 1);
            count = 1;
        }
        nextName = nextNames[nextName];
    }

    return res.concat(unsortedNamesCopy);
}

console.log(sortNames(names));
console.log(sortNames(namesWithUnknown));
```

Comment: I notice this only works for the example names I provided in the question. Would you be able to modify this so it works for any array that is passed in containing names. (e.g. if I pass another array such as ["John", "Larry", "Randy", "Randy", "John", "Larry"] this function would not work.)

Comment: Ok, so you have 2 options I think :

First, you pass a second parameter `nextNames` to the function, and you adapt it (so `let nextName = "Jewel";` becomes `let nextName = nextNames[0];`...

Second solution, you suppose the pattern is for exemple the 3 first elements of the array you passed, so you init nextNames `const nextNames = {unsortedNames[0]: unsortedNames[1], unsortedNames[1]: unsortedNames[2], unsortedNames[2]: unsortedNames[0]};` and `let nextName = unsortedNames[0]`

Is it the solution you need ?

Comment: That sounds like it may work, let me give it a try and I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are still quite unclear.  Here's one attempt that makes the following assumptions:

- The pattern is to repeat one of each name in the same order... at least until we run out of instances of a given name, then repeat one of each of the remaining ones, etc.  Thus `['Jewel', 'Crown', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Jewel', 'Rob', 'Crown', 'Jewel', 'Rob']` could become `['Rob', 'Jewel', 'Crown', 'Rob', 'Jewel', 'Crown', 'Rob', 'Jewel', 'Rob', 'Rob']`, where we include `['Rob', 'Jewel', 'Crown']` twice, then run out of `'Crown'`s and include `['Rob', 'Jewel']` once, then run our of `'Jewel'`s, and include the (one) remaining `'Rob'`.  Perhaps you know that your input is balanced and you don't have to worry about this scenario, but it doesn't hurt much.
- The initial order does not matter at all. Instead of `['Jewel', 'Crown', 'Rob', 'Jewel', 'Crown', 'Rob']` this would be equally valid: `['Rob', 'Crown', 'Jewel', 'Rob', 'Crown', 'Jewel'].
- Your values are strings or something else that can serve as object keys.

The implementation looks like this:

```js
const counts = (names) => 
  Object .entries (names .reduce ((a, n) => ((a [n] = (a [n] || 0) + 1), a), {}))

const reorder = (cs, counts = cs .filter (([_, c]) => c > 0) .sort (([, a], [, b]) => b - a)) => counts .length
  ? [...counts .map (([n]) => n), ...reorder (counts .map (([n, c]) => [n, c - 1])) ] 
  : []

const rearrange = (names) => reorder (counts (names))

console .log (rearrange (["Jewel", "Crown", "Rob", "Rob", "Jewel", "Crown"]))
console .log (rearrange (["Jewel", "Crown", "Rob", "Rob", "Rob", "Jewel", "Rob", "Crown"]))
console .log (rearrange (["John", "Larry", "Randy", "Randy", "John", "Larry"]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We have two helper functions.  The first, `count` turns your array into an array of pairs, containing the value and the count of the value in the original array, sorted descending by the counts.  For instance:

```
counts (['Rob', 'Jewel', 'Crown', 'Rob', 'Jewel', 'Crown', 'Rob', 'Jewel', 'Rob', 'Rob])
  //=> `[['Rob', 5], ['Jewel', 3], ['Crown', 2]]`
```

The second one, `reorder` does the real work, extracting one of each of the elements that still have a count, reducing all the counts by one, and recurring, stopping with an empty array when there are no more non-empty sets.

The main function `rearrange` just composes those two functions.